# Store async data in recycler view

Tags: android, asynchronous, tabs, android-recyclerview, contacts

I have a main activity in which i have used a view pager.So i can move between 4 tabs and the view pager handles all of that.One of my tabs scans the contacts on the phone to get their details and display it in the recylerview which is in the same tab,this task takes a long time and i am doing this in an async task.Everything is working fine but the problem is if i move to another tab while this scanning is going on the data does not get applied to the recycler view possible because that fragment is being destroyed.
Is there a workaround for this or should i just prevent the user from shifting tabs while the scanning is going on (if so some sort of code or a link to the code would be really helpfull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you force a user to stay on a page whilst data loads. This sounds like it would only frustrate people. To that end, I have a couple of ideas that should keep your `AsyncTask` running whilst your `Fragment` isn't visible.

First, you could call [`setOffScreenPageLimit(2)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) on your `ViewPager`. As you only have four `Fragment`s, this should mean all of them are stored in memory.

```
viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(2);
```

Another approach is you may be able to create a UI-less `Fragment` whose sole function is to conduct your `AsyncTask` and then, once it reaches `onPostExecute()`, pass the `Cursor` result to the `Fragment` that requires it with either an `interface` or an EventBus of some sort (i.e. [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or one of the other many excellent libraries that exist, such as GreenRobot's EventBus).

**Edit** If you like information on how to create such a "worker" `Fragment`, then there is a very good and detailed post on [androiddesignpatterns](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html).

Comment: Was planning on setting the offscreenlimit but i wasn't sure how much of a memory hit that might be.Does is consume alot of memory?

Comment: @JudeFernandes The javadoc entry says to try and keep the number as low as you can, but as the minimum amount of `Fragment`s cached by a `ViewPager` is three, realistically four shouldn't cause an issue.